# WordPress: How to redirect a specific user to a specific page everytime? This is not about after logging-in

Tags: php, wordpress

I use WordPress.

I know how to redirect a user to a specific page after logging in. But let's say they have already logged-in and they click specific URL, they should be redirected to another.

Sample:
usernameA The user has already logged-in. He clicks domainname.com/my-account He will be redirected to domainname.com/pageA

usernameB The user has already logged-in. He clicks domainname.com/my-account He will be redirected to domainname.com/pageB

All of them click the domainname.com/my-account but they have to be redirected to a different page.

This redirection is per user. Is there a way to do this in function.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built-in wp_redirect() function. Use a hook where there has been no output yet but wordpress already has the necessary info, like the requested post_id. you can stick something like this in your functions.php

```
function myredirect() {
   $page_id = get_queried_object_id();

   //im working with the id's here, but for better readability you can also work with slugs. 
   //you shouldnt use the whole url, because it will mean trouble when changing/moving domain-names
   //
   //check if it's the page you want to redirect from.
   if($page_id==138) {
       $user_id=get_current_user_id();
       $redirect_to='';
       switch($user_id) {
           case 1:
               $redirect_to=54840;
               break;
       }
       if(!empty($redirect_to)) {
           wp_redirect(get_permalink($redirect_to));
           exit;
       }
   }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'myredirect');
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much! But it did not work on my end. This is what I did:  function myredirect() {
   $page_id = get_queried_object_id();
 if($page_id==72) {
       $user_id=3();
       $redirect_to='111';
       switch($user_id) {
           case 1:
               $redirect_to=111;
               break;
       }
       if(!empty($redirect_to)) {
           wp_redirect(get_permalink($redirect_to));
           exit;
       }
   }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'myredirect'); But did not work.

Comment: $user_id=3(); 
  $redirect_to='111'; 
i guess this is for testing. the brackets here: 3(), are certainly wrong. they would even cause a php error.  i copy/pasted your code, took only the brackets behind the 3 out and set my own values, and it works.

btw, here is some doc about the hook in use: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect

Comment: Thank you for the help. I do really appreciate it!